# Multiply Matrices in DAX

Tags: matrix, powerbi, linear-algebra, matrix-multiplication, dax

Suppose I have two matrices `MatrixA` and `MatrixB` given as follows (where `i` is the row number and `j` is the column number:

```
 MatrixA       |   MatrixB

 i | j | val   |   i | j | val
---|---|----   |  ---|---|----
 1 | 1 |  3    |   1 | 1 |  2
 1 | 2 |  5    |   1 | 2 |  3
 1 | 3 |  9    |   2 | 1 |  7
 2 | 1 |  2    |   2 | 2 | -1
 2 | 2 |  1    |   3 | 1 |  0
 2 | 3 |  3    |   3 | 2 | -4
 3 | 1 |  3    |
 3 | 2 | -1    |
 3 | 3 |  2    |
 4 | 1 |  0    |
 4 | 2 |  7    |
 4 | 3 |  6    |
```

In a more familiar form, they look like this:

```
 MatrixA =  3  5  9   MatrixB =  2  3
            2  1  3              7 -1
           -1  2  0              0 -4
            7  0  6
```

I'd like to calculate their product (which is demonstrated in [this YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N3WT8_TWDYs)):

```
Product =  41  -32
           11   -7
           12   -5
           14   -3
```

In the unpivoted column form I used earlier, this is

```
 i | j | val
---|---|----
 1 | 1 |  41
 1 | 2 | -32
 2 | 1 |  11
 2 | 2 |  -7
 3 | 1 |  12
 3 | 2 |  -5
 4 | 1 |  12
 4 | 2 |  -3
```

I'm looking for a general calculation that multiplies any compatible `k x n` and `n x m` matrices together as a calculated table.

Comment: I'm just curious why would you have matrices in such weird format in Power BI in the first place?

Comment: @FoxanNg It's really the only format that makes sense to me due to the columnar nature of DAX. Do you have a better suggestion for their format?

Comment: That is such a strange representation of a matrix

Comment: @AlexisOlson I would actually suggest not to do the matrix multiplication in Power BI in the first place. Now with both Python and R scripts available in Power BI, it will just be a one-liner for both languages to do so. Although I'm not sure how your data pipeline is and how you obtain the matrices, this may or may not be the best approach for you.

Comment: @FoxanNg The problem with that is that everything must be precomputed. You can't get dynamic interaction with slicers unless you're using DAX or else precompute all possible slicer setting combinations, which is often not feasible.

Comment: @StelioK It's just an unpivoted table, a fairly standard normalization for tabular data.

Comment: @AlexisOlson I've just never seen that form before, I dig it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I've got it figured out. If `MatrixA` is `k x n` and `MatrixB` is `n x m` dimensional:

```
Product = 
   ADDCOLUMNS(
       CROSSJOIN(VALUES(MatrixA[i]), VALUES(MatrixB[j])),
       "val",
       SUMX(
          ADDCOLUMNS(
             SELECTCOLUMNS(GENERATESERIES(1, DISTINCTCOUNT(MatrixA[j])), "Index", [Value]),
             "A", LOOKUPVALUE(MatrixA[val], MatrixA[i], [i], MatrixA[j], [Index]),
             "B", LOOKUPVALUE(MatrixB[val], MatrixB[i], [Index], MatrixB[j], [j])),
          [A] * [B]))
```

The `CROSSJOIN` creates a new table with columns `[i]` and `[j]` which has `k x m` rows. For each `i` and `j` row pair in this cross join table, the value for that cell is computed as the sum product of `i` row of `MatrixA` with `j` column of `MatrixB`. The `GENERATESERIES` bit just creates an `Index` list that has a length of the matching dimension `n`.

For example, when `i = 3` and `j = 2`, the middle section for the given example is

```
ADDCOLUMNS(
    SELECTCOLUMNS(GENERATESERIES(1, DISTINCTCOUNT(MatrixA[j])), "Index", [Value]),
    "A", LOOKUPVALUE(MatrixA[val], MatrixA[i], 3, MatrixA[j], [Index]),
    "B", LOOKUPVALUE(MatrixB[val], MatrixB[i], [Index], MatrixB[j], 2))
```

which generates the table

```
Index |  A  |  B
------|-----|----
 1    | -1  |  3
 2    |  2  | -1
 3    |  0  | -4
```

where the `[A]` column is the 3rd row of `MatrixA` and the `[B]` column is the 2nd row of `MatrixB`.